# Big o value of sample program

Tags: python, algorithm

Im trying to big o worst case scenario for a programming logic and need some clarification.

Here is a very simple program, it takes a number - 2938023 and each char is multiplied by a random number and populated in a list.

Once the list is populated, I get the max value as my result.

```
from random import randint
def test(A):
    result = []
    for each in str(A):
        result.append(int(each)*randint(0,9))   
    return max(result)


print test(2938023)
```

What is the big o worst case of this operation? As the list - str(A) is iterated only once, should I consider it to be log(n) or

Should I consider it n*n as the list is again iterated to get the max value. There is 2 pass on the list based on n.

Comment: how do you get `log`? also why is this tagged `c++`? you can calculate the `max` in the `for-loop` itself

Comment: It's O(N). The list is iterated exactly 2n times, so dropping the constant factor, that is O(N). I don't see where you get the log...

Comment: @Oswald yeah, although it is important to point out that doesn't change the Big-Oh complexity.

Comment: Also might be important to note that the list append is O(1), which isn't true for all list operations.

Comment: Log is a typo.. it's just n* n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the comments have given a pretty clear answer - but just to clarify (and also properly answer the question):

The two operations that define the big-O here is:

- `for each in str(A):` - This is an `O(n)` operation, it looks at each character in the string (`A`).
- `max(result)` - This is also an `O(n)`, as we have to iterate the entire list to fix the maximum (`result`).

Since `len(A) == len(result)` we can call this `2n` (as opposed to `nm`), and since it's big-O, we drop the constant factor, resulting in: `O(n)`.

If you wanted to remove the constant factor entirely you could rewrite the function as:

```
from random import randint
def test(A):
    max_item = 0
    for each in str(A):
        new_item = int(each)*randint(0,9)
        if new_item > max_item:
            max_item = new_item  
    return max_item
```

Which is also `O(n)`, but only iterates the string.